# Syntax error near unexpected token 'then'

Tags: linux, shell, unix

I typed the code the same as [The Linux Command Line: A Complete Introduction](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1593273894), page 369
but prompt the error:

```
line 7 `if[ -e "$FILE" ]; then`
```

the code is like:

```
#!/bin/bash
#test file exists

FILE="1"
if[ -e "$FILE" ]; then
  if[ -f "$FILE" ]; then
     echo :"$FILE is a regular file"
  fi
  if[ -d "$FILE" ]; then
     echo "$FILE is a directory"
  fi
else 
   echo "$FILE does not exit"
   exit 1
fi
   exit
```

I want to figure out what introduced the error. How can I modify the code? My system is Ubuntu.

Comment: Check https://shellcheck.net. The question is a bit old but for anyone else encountering such syntax errors, shellcheck is a great tool.

Answer (score 93, accepted):

There must be a space between `if` and `[`, like this:

```
#!/bin/bash
#test file exists

FILE="1"
if [ -e "$FILE" ]; then
  if [ -f "$FILE" ]; then
     echo :"$FILE is a regular file"
  fi
...
```

These (and their combinations) would all be *incorrect* too:

```
if [-e "$FILE" ]; then
if [ -e"$FILE" ]; then
if [ -e "$FILE"]; then
```

These on the other hand are all ok:

```
if [ -e "$FILE" ];then  # no spaces around ;
if     [    -e   "$FILE"    ]   ;   then  # 1 or more spaces are ok
```

Btw these are equivalent:

```
if [ -e "$FILE" ]; then
if test -e "$FILE"; then
```

These are also equivalent:

```
if [ -e "$FILE" ]; then echo exists; fi
[ -e "$FILE" ] && echo exists
test -e "$FILE" && echo exists
```

And, the middle part of your script would have been better with an `elif` like this:

```
if [ -f "$FILE" ]; then
    echo $FILE is a regular file
elif [ -d "$FILE" ]; then
    echo $FILE is a directory
fi
```

(I also dropped the quotes in the `echo`, as in this example they are unnecessary)

Comment: The reason you need a space is because [ is actually a command. Type `which [` and you will see that it is in /bin/. You can write any `if [...]; then` command as `if test ...`.

Answer (score 3):

The solution is pretty simple.
Just give space between if and the opening square braces like given below.

`if [ -f  "$File" ]; then
<code>
fi`